# Issue accessing a relation in a PHP object

Tags: php, oop, laravel-4

I am using Laravel 4 and have this line:

```
$report = DeliveryProfitReport::where('id', $id)->with('car_info', 'basic_customer')->get();
```

I would normally then access the 'car_info' like so:

```
$report->car_info->id
```

But I am getting errors this time:

```
Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$car_info
```

The object looks like this (if I dd() $report):

```
object(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection)#823 (1) {
  ["items":protected] array(1) {
    [0] object(DeliveryProfitReport)#798 (20) {
      ["table":protected] "delivery_profit_reports"
      ["guarded":protected] array(0) {
     }
     ["connection":protected] NULL
     ["primaryKey":protected] "id"
     ["perPage":protected] 15
     ["incrementing"] true
     ["timestamps"] true
     ["attributes":protected] array(29) {
       ["id"] "13"
       ["updated_at"] "2015-07-15 10:11:39"
       ["created_at"] "2015-07-15 10:11:39"
     }
     ["original":protected] array(29) {
       ["id"] "13"
       ["updated_at"] "2015-07-15 10:11:39"
       ["created_at"] "2015-07-15 10:11:39"
     }
     ["relations":protected] array(2) {
       ["car_info"] object(Car)#801 (29) {
         ["connection":protected] "main_site"
         ["timestamps"] false
         ["hidden":protected] array(7) {
           [0] "basic_incl_options"
         }
... and so on.
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is `get()` returns an array.

Change to `first()`:

```
$report = DeliveryProfitReport::where('id', $id)->with('car_info', 'basic_customer')->first();
```

Which will remove the top level array in your `dd()`.

Otherwise, you'll have to do something like:

`$report[0]->car_info->id`

or `$report = $report[0];` and then `$report->car_info->id`

Comment: That didn't work and still returned an error. But ->first() did.

Comment: That makes sense since `dd()` returned an array containing an object. `first()` removed the top level array. To confirm that, can you see if `$report[0]->car_info->id` works with `get()`?

Answer (score 0):

This is because `get()` return multi-dimensional array. You can't directly access to your object. Try to use `first()` instead.

```
$report = DeliveryProfitReport::where('id', $id)->with('car_info', 'basic_customer')->get();

$report->first()->car_info;
```

Hope it will be useful for you